# True for one, Not for the other

Tags: lateral-thinking, story

I came up with puzzle, I think it's clever.

> Two women, Eve and Amy, sit at a table. After a bit of casual chit chat. Amy, writes on a piece of paper and says “I wrote five words. It is a true statement, but I bet you five dollars that you will read a false statement.” Eve accepts the bet and reads the paper. She loses and pays Amy the five dollars, but Amy did not lie.
>
> The phrase was not based on the person who wrote it or the wording Amy used, and later if Eve wrote the same five words and made the bet to someone, Eve would have won. What was written on the paper?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe it was

> Only one person read this

Answer (score 3):

Are the words on the paper

> “You’ll read ‘a false one’”?

Because

> It’s a true statement, since Eve, by reading the paper, will read “a false one” and will therefore owe Amy $5.

Further,

> This statement is not based on person, since if Eve wrote “You’ll read ‘a false one’” on the paper and made the bet with Amy, Eve would have won as well.

Answer (score 2):

The five words could be:

> It is 3:00:00 right now (or whatever other time it is, accurate to the second)

Reasoning:

> When Eve reads the paper, it must have been at least a second since Amy wrote it, making it a false statement.

Comment: That answer makes sense, but it's not the one I had. But out of curiosity should I fix the riddle based on answers that would work, but not the ones I'm looking for?

Comment: @McNiko67 it's your decision, honestly. Part of the fun is seeing what different answers people come up with, but if you want to see the answer that you had in mind, feel free to edit it.

Answer (score 1):

I see you accepted an answer, but what about...

> "I wrote these five words."

Which would be true because...

> Amy wrote them, so it is a true statement. But when Eve reads them aloud, she is making a false statement (since Amy wrote them).

One could argue that my answer is wrong because...

> It's possibly forbidden by your rules (i.e., the phrase can't be based on the person who wrote it) but the accepted answer is also pretty close to being about the person who wrote it too.

Comment: the answer is about who read it, not who wrote it. Your answer is incorrect.

Comment: Why is it incorrect? Eve read the note. The note said, "I wrote these five words." That's a false statement because she didn't write them; Amy did.

Comment: because the riddle states the "the phrase is not about who wrote it." as to try to eliminate the alternative answers (which you can't eliminate everything, but I wanted to to limit it so the true answer feels like the one that should fit, rather than people saying "well this would also work...")